# heroku returns 200 then 403

Tags: heroku, flask

I've deployed a Flask web app to heroku.
The code works on my localhost, and I think nothing is wrong with my Procfile.
In fact, everything works properly at the beginning (everything returns 200, even the POST requests). It's just that, after that initial functionality, POST requests start returning 403. You can see in the logs that this happens. Is it because I am sending too many POST requests at once and am getting denied?

```
2017-06-20T16:01:16.845941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:server`
2017-06-20T16:01:20.096712+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-20 16:01:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2017-06-20T16:01:20.097775+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-20 16:01:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:46337 (4)
2017-06-20T16:01:20.097995+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-20 16:01:20 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-06-20T16:01:20.189950+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-20 16:01:20 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2017-06-20T16:01:20.105157+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-20 16:01:20 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2017-06-20T16:01:21.127714+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-06-20T16:01:34.961499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=b5ab4dbc-2d55-4cb7-9352-f1428388cbf4 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12690ms status=200 bytes=928 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:36.097253+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/_config" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=15867602-581e-4b9d-9c39-2a455d48ac19 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=449 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:36.194579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=ff2908a6-d3f5-41a4-b2ed-745c0b6f4e56 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=80ms status=200 bytes=745 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:36.297555+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/layout" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=afe00afa-345f-4c17-af03-09e6a995aec7 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=166ms status=200 bytes=2655 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:36.372381+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dependencies" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=d45adf72-4ba3-4323-b1a4-eb0666403523 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=214ms status=200 bytes=658 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:36.521571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/routes" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=6a01682e-921a-412f-be80-fb0d8806b5cd fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=356ms status=200 bytes=296 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:36.636388+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=333bb498-c4e6-4a38-ba48-186e1acf471b fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=79ms status=200 bytes=390 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:36.701389+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=2607a2e9-a833-41f4-ad8c-77c3cb851884 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=141ms status=200 bytes=390 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:36.776266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=9289d621-93da-4188-bc28-e943067b700d fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=213ms status=200 bytes=390 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:37.018956+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=c17fecd8-4e21-4969-8d1c-b38cbef4b0bc fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=423ms status=200 bytes=693 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:36.880369+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=bb3f15ea-7e72-41c0-a388-d828e144c4c1 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=312ms status=200 bytes=390 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:37.151601+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=379c8719-7631-49d9-bb21-23e3a4f4bef0 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=413ms status=200 bytes=519 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:37.148173+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=7d41ebe8-26e2-4671-b434-028bf43c6773 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=490ms status=200 bytes=693 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:37.088971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=d945240d-5028-4956-957b-5c71065ac36f fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=492ms status=200 bytes=569 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:37.274916+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=49a2a6bb-6d59-4a42-8b91-3333486addf9 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=475ms status=200 bytes=569 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:37.376558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=53b5eafc-16e7-4f35-84d3-d3a1756b4a48 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=466ms status=200 bytes=693 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:37.396808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=b52eba0b-e57e-4adb-8a82-b25e4bf14dcf fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=347ms status=200 bytes=519 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:37.701174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=acdd65df-09c5-4c3e-981c-f5ca5a565cdb fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=563ms status=200 bytes=569 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:37.974959+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=64bcf02e-56f1-4bf7-89ee-c197e5b69cc2 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=807ms status=200 bytes=693 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:38.038246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=3bf8712a-8bc4-4b02-b9b2-a88b7d345567 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=860ms status=200 bytes=519 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:38.207441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=54ef1b9a-6aaf-4c15-bc8c-ed14952100e6 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=913ms status=200 bytes=569 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.123170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=b5d4b23f-ee9e-40c4-9ffb-26c77d1463be fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=1709ms status=200 bytes=693 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.318840+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=ac0a9929-97d7-4b53-b090-b05445e64c1b fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1593ms status=200 bytes=569 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.247560+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=20513249-f8f0-4487-ba16-1e1999a4d85e fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1820ms status=200 bytes=519 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.404262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=0ac2c9e2-a6f7-40a7-9771-923226a42d99 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1401ms status=200 bytes=693 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.439102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=bf0a9d96-5774-4672-b983-77a4dd86145f fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1371ms status=200 bytes=519 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.583746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=08818e38-e4c3-44cf-8f06-4a3c37a28bdb fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=307ms status=200 bytes=519 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.602835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=e78d5178-4c66-4319-9c1b-75ff0ede45e1 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=261ms status=200 bytes=569 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.643553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=50a38891-0e93-4c9a-b343-691ea2c042d1 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=342 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.533893+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=28a35bbe-ae16-4805-8cfb-45952d21bb34 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1303ms status=200 bytes=569 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.577065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=a7ac8bb1-8abc-4484-ad96-2b02ece88e63 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=391ms status=200 bytes=693 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.634418+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=a26ad4a1-a0cb-44fb-858a-7ce6f6e1e41b fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=340 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.611004+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=9cdd1c45-7177-4d1b-891d-1565d01bad6c fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=180ms status=200 bytes=519 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.633465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=8a12dfe0-78d8-4625-8199-be2fac659621 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=70ms status=200 bytes=340 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.627790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=1f5738ab-f8f0-4ad3-a99c-7b15a6b65341 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=155ms status=200 bytes=569 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.639930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=dd4c1303-d43e-4701-88ce-199af52eddeb fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=342 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.931248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=d289254b-c2ed-46f9-b630-2567c921faf3 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=58ms status=200 bytes=752 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.907817+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=96934c6b-2d79-4c67-8560-c56ea87ef0fd fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=44ms status=200 bytes=752 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.874176+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=b0b6e178-9122-4cb9-a461-c3f6d4e50916 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=38ms status=200 bytes=334 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:39.880939+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=5f690c51-5f56-476d-aa78-f63d32263d82 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=334 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:40.056507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=32f54ee2-6296-4f19-96a7-9f6f511b9687 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=133ms status=200 bytes=1201 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:40.433124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=84a8aaea-4a94-4fe8-a2c5-60c52252f7fd fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=499ms status=200 bytes=1201 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:43.246410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=6d85aea6-c5a0-4f81-bf3f-f87e90f61cc3 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=446 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:43.316244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=3503b089-1258-4932-b76e-7d66efa76025 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=84ms status=403 bytes=713 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:43.256630+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=4873d69a-3eb7-4db8-adcb-97d4a254cbee fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=22ms status=200 bytes=446 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:43.369376+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=b3481570-b6db-43e7-8397-32d3c9da6caf fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=48ms status=200 bytes=353 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:01:43.378513+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=2526588e-d5ba-40ae-891e-644c899ffa9f fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=60ms status=403 bytes=713 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:12.288966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=2ed53537-afac-44cd-b16f-c661f674a497 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=200 bytes=928 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.074652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/_config" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=fcbcf27e-1044-446f-bd56-29c5aac0cfb5 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=632 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.161220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/routes" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=6ba9c7de-c6d2-45cc-abab-7f8dc05227de fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=53ms status=200 bytes=479 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.128897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=6980591e-0aef-4397-b65e-8d37bf470e29 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=29ms status=200 bytes=745 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.166240+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dependencies" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=fb2babe3-fc1e-4af3-90ce-65d521d0dcd5 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=56ms status=200 bytes=658 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.253139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=b204c6f3-646b-4008-813a-ccde5e516735 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=21ms status=403 bytes=713 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.145435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/layout" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=4ce2faec-c7f9-49ee-b991-430c97a18216 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=36ms status=200 bytes=2655 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.270867+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=a5aaea09-0e0c-46f4-9000-afb723e1644e fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=40ms status=403 bytes=530 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.370679+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=b50f0119-c4d7-4b58-b6f6-03ee0e68fca1 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=67ms status=403 bytes=530 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.302148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=0b91008e-2351-4663-a974-3e3b7c50fdba fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=33ms status=403 bytes=530 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.238984+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=f363408f-b5b1-4606-b526-c844bd83fdc7 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=403 bytes=530 protocol=http
2017-06-20T16:02:13.413000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/update-component" host=guidelinereview.herokuapp.com request_id=845af0e7-9806-457a-a35b-7263ce8a4f01 fwd="71.206.29.171" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=91ms status=403 bytes=530 protocol=http
...
```

How would I solve this problem? There is lots of interactivity on the site.

Comment: Are you using a token anywhere in your code responsible for handling the POST request?

Comment: No, I'm not. I didn't need it for a local host, but would I need it for hosting on the cloud?